# Show that $n+1$ is prime if (Denominator(Bernoulli Number($n$)))/($n+1$) is an integer

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers, bernoulli-numbers

I suspect this is true, but I'm having trouble proving it. Here are some example cases:

$$6/3=2$$
$$30/5=7$$
$$66/11=6$$
...
$$9538864545210/241=39580350810$$

and I suppose a few examples of it not being an integer for composite numbers is a good idea:

$$30/9=3.\overline{33}$$
$$6/15=.4$$
$$330/21=110/7\approx15.7143$$
...
$$30/249\approx0.120482$$

In my last [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2713657/sum-of-the-first-integer-powers-of-n-up-to-k), I noticed a few extremely intriguing properties (previously known); one of which is that the polynomial solutions to the sum of the first powers of n up to k have coefficients related to the Bernoulli numbers. Another is that these coefficients (as required for these polynomials to product integers) sum to one. I have noticed quite a few more things, but I'm not sure they are relevant.

The reason I ask this is because I further suspect that this could potentially reveal some useful relationships about prime numbers, and the Bernoulli numbers. (Disclaimer: I am not a professional mathematician. If I miss something obvious, please be kind).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a theorem known as [Von Staudt-Clausen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Staudt%E2%80%93Clausen_theorem) that shows, as direct consequence of the nature of Bernoulli numbers, that Bernoulli fractions have unique prime denominators.

Specifically, every Bernoulli expansion has factors of (n+1) in it, and no integers other than prime integers can divide the denominator of $B_n$.